# Does all api has an end point? and is end point always an URL?

Tags: javascript, api, rest

Im Studying the concept of API and it is a bit confusing, since i used REST API which accept Get, Post, Put, Delete and everytime i need to use it i will need an URL, so Does all api has an end point? and is end point always an URL?

Comment: An API is an "application programmer interface" which is a nifty way of describing a list of descriptions that say "when you do X, we will do Y and return Z to you". A REST API is a specific type of API where the "do X" part is a HTTP request. But an API can also be a set of classes/interfaces/methods in your favorite programming language.

Answer (score 2):

*"so Does all api has an end point?"*

For REST: yes.

For other APIs: No, not every API has an endpoint.

*"and is end point always an URL?"*

No, you don't always need a URL. There are many APIs using URIs. All URLs are URIs but not all URIs are URLs.

URL is necessary in context of HTTP. You can write your own TCP API without URL.

Answer (score 1):

With REST API, it is. You know, REST is a standard used in designing APIs for web applications, and in the web the client and server will communicate with each other using a url with methods like get, post, ..

Comment: REST is often used outside the web, e.g. Docker client communicates with Docker daemon through Unix socket with REST. There is no network and no web involved. You shouldn't limit the answer to web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Not all API's have endpoints. Some have routines, others have classes, etc. For example, a procedural language (like C) would have routines. An object oriented language would have classes. These would be exposed somehow, so that they can be consumed. It really depends on what language the API has been developed.

On the other hand, a Web API exposes a service typically through URL endpoints. Nowadays modern API's make use of [REST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/REST) which basically entails:

- A base [URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/URI)
- Standard HTTP [Request Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) (GET, PUT, PATCH, POST and DELETE)
- A [media type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application) (`application/json`, `application/xml`, etc.)